# Canadian Journal of Mathematics Style & Font

Tags: fonts, header-footer, journal-publishing, blackboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture)

So if you look at CJM (it needs subscription online so I can't link to examples) it has a very distinct style and font. I was wondering if anyone knows what font and what kind of style they are using (I have not seen their blackboard bold anywhere else) and whether it is freely available.

Comment: If you have a subscription, you can paste a screenshot of a document so others can also view the font. Otherwise you may be shooting at a very specific audience...

Comment: I found an old Erdos paper [here](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1959-25.pdf). The style has probably changed since then though.

Comment: i haven't seen a current issue, but in 1999, i had a communication from the person who does the composition that he was trying out viva-regular, and "had no complaints from authors".  whether this made it into actual production, i'm not sure.  google "viva font" for more information.

Comment: @Werner I will try to post a screenshot soon

Comment: @Everitt no that is not what I am talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Every reputable math journal that I'm aware of tries to give you the LaTeX information you need to submit a paper. So I did a quick search and found [this](http://math.ca/cjm/authors) page. In the section "Preparing a manuscript for submission" it says,"The CMS recommends LaTeX for manuscript preparation and has prepared a sample LaTeX file for author review which generates this PDF output. Please ensure your pages are numbered, beginning with 1. For further information about style, formats, the use of LaTeX and the production of PDF output, contact the CMS by e-mail at: tex-editor@cms.math.ca."

At the page I've linked to you'll find you can download a sample tex file and the PDF output it provides. The e-mail ought to get you the answers that you might still have after checking out the .tex file.

Comment: I am not submitting a paper I am just wondering whether their font and style is available somewhere. And sample LaTeX file in your link is just plain CM fonts and a simple article type style ...

Comment: I was only trying to say the information is typically available for anyone submitting a paper so it should be easily found. From above, "For further information about style, formats...contact the CMS by e-mail at: tex-editor@cms.math.ca." so a quick e-mail should get your questions. They almost certainly have the most current style files, too.